# Child python process is getting stuck

Tags: python, docker, flask, aws-fargate

Before we start, I am doing everything in a Python container (AWS Fargate) so hence some limitations.

I am using Flask module to run a web-server and spawn a permanent child process with multiprocessing module to run repetitive background tasks. Everything is working fine but at night the child process is getting stuck randomly with no logs or traces. I've even run a custom health check to make sure it's alive and it kind of is, but it stops working, CPU usage drops and I can't understand what is going on. It is doing a lot of networks calls but I would expect it to terminate on timeout, not hang. CPU usage is sitting flat on ~40% while it's working and RAM is constant at 18%. Potentially it could run out of file descriptors but why would it?

The code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def poll():
    while True:
        blablabla
        time.sleep(60)

p = Process(target=poll)
p.start()
p.join

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def java():
    return app.send_static_file('java.html')
```

I can't use any timeouts because the child process is meant to run indefinitely and I can't spawn a new process every few minutes because container's kernel will run out of PIDs fairly soon. I don't see how I can use "try" too since it's not failing but just getting unresponsive.

Technically, I can run another container for this subjob but I wonder if there is a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, need more information to offer help, what is the blablabla part of the code actually doing?  Have you tried add logging to each line of that part to determine where in the code its hanging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `blahblahblah` exits, `poll()` will loop indefinitely, and your initial process will get stuck on waiting for a `.join()` that will never happen.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join

Comment: That's right. I wonder how did it work initially but it somehow did.. Nevertheless, I added another watchdog child process to monitor the first fork based on a timed flag and turned out the both processes get stuck simultaneously so my problem is somewhere at the container layer.